# Turn Tasker on and off with a widget

Tags: tasker

I would like to create 2 widgets to turn Tasker on and off (Enable and Disable tasker).

If it helps, I have Secure Settings and Zooper Widget. My phone is also rooted.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to just create two *Tasker* tasks for that, and then use Tasker's own widget to trigger them?

Comment: I thought of it, but I don't know how to go about doing that. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer in advance: I didn't try this myself – so I'm not sure if the "turning on" part will work.</sup>

1. In Tasker: Create a task to stop the Tasker service (*Tasker › Disable*)
2. In Tasker: <s>Create a task to start the Tasker service</s>
3. On your homescreen, add a Tasker-widget (Tasker ships with that), and connect it with the Task.

So when you hit that widget for #1, *Tasker* will be disabled. You will have noticed the strike-through at #2: If *Tasker* is not active, it does not listen – so there is no such action. From the *Tasker* help on "Disable":

> Permanently turn off Tasker's Monitor and stop running tasks.
>   Tasker will not do anything further until **enabled via the On/Off button** in the Profile List screen.

So I am afraid that's all you can get: a widget to disable Tasker, but none to (re-) enable it.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I was afraid of. Guess I'll just have to make do then. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Afraid so, yes. If the answer helped you, you can "upvote" it (that's how we say "thanks" at SE ;). If it answered your question, please "accept" it by clicking the check-mark next to it (makes it easier for other searchers to identify it as "solved").

Comment: Since I don't have enough rep for an upvote, I can only mark as solved. Here you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You can create a stand alone app (export as app) in Tasker. The stand alone app should start Tasker and use AutoInput Plugin to long click on the Enable Tasker icon.

Then just click the Enable Tasker (exported app). Not so elegant but it works.

I cant find any 'Enable Tasker' action but there should be a shortcut or something so we can make it elegant :-)

Comment: "I cant find any 'Enable Tasker' action" – there must be some intent you could call to do that, which you could create a task for. Apart from that: no need to have/create an additional app for that, as my answer shows :)

Comment: You find the tasker enable button when you start tasker. Try long hold on the tasker icon up left corner. I dont know if a intent exists for that. But if you got autoinput you can long press it. The stand alone app is needed because, like you sad, tasker wont listen to the tasker widgets when tasker is disabled. You can create a stand alone app that can start the tasker service.

Comment: I know about that *button* – but that I've got to press with my fingers, you cannot trigger it automatically ;)

Comment: You can use a tasker plugin called AutoInput (dont need root) to press it automatically. No real fingers needed :-)